# Can't stage files or commit them to Bitbucket via Git Bash

Tags: git, addition, commit

I have everything set up locally, and I was able to echo, add, and commit a .txt file to my repo @ Bitbucket

https://bitbucket.org/mkov88/treehouse-portfolio-site

in the same directory as the .txt file i have a basic website setup.

Index.html
CSS folder
IMG folder

when I try to git add . or git add index.html the line executes with no error message but when I do git status it says the working directory is clean with nothing to commit.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You already have an `index.html` in the repo. Perhaps you didn't change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `git status` will show up every file that has been modify on your project directory. If a file does not appear there that means that either it doesn't exists, or you haven't modified that file since the last commit.

If you modified the file make sure you have saved it and try checking the status again.

If you are new to learning git I suggest to check out the [trygit](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) tutorial. It's great!

Comment: I edited all of the files and then they showed up. I guess I'm going to run into a lot of little quirks like this. Thanks for the answer.